# Eliminating a while loop

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have this code and i am wondering if it can be executed without the while loop.

```
quantity <- vector()        
while (length(quantity) < 2) {                
       Random <- runif(10, 0, 1)                   
       quantity <- which(Random < 0.3)        
}
quantity
```

Comment: Since it's unclear how many iterations it will take to finish, a `while` loop is most appropriate here. Not sure why you are trying to eliminate the `while` loop here; what exactly do you want to replace it with?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a recursive function.

```
set.seed(42)
foo <- function() {
  random <- runif(10, 0, 1)
  quantity <- which(random < .3)
  if (length(quantity) >= 2) return(quantity)
  else return(foo())
}
foo()
# [1] 3 8
```

*Check:*

```
set.seed(42)
quantity <- vector()        
while (length(quantity) < 2) {                
  Random <- runif(10, 0, 1)                   
  quantity <- which(Random < 0.3)        
}
quantity 
# [1] 3 8
```

Comment: I doubt the recursive function is quite as fast as your benchmark makes out.

Comment: @Hugh I am also surprised, you may try it yourself: `microbenchmark::microbenchmark('while'={quantity <- vector();while (length(quantity) < 2) {Random <- runif(10, 0, 1);quantity <- which(Random < 0.3)};quantity},foo=foo())`

Comment: I think it's the fact that `foo` is a function. Consider wrapping your first in `local` then you don't get the difference. `microbenchmark::microbenchmark('while'=local({quantity <- vector();while (length(quantity) < 2) {Random <- runif(10, 0, 1);quantity <- which(Random < 0.3)};quantity}),foo=foo())`

Comment: @Hugh I'm sure now the bench is false. Interesting I never used `local`. However I get even different results when also wrapping `local(foo))`. So I wrapped the `while` code into a function and now get similar results to `foo`.

Comment: I think what's happening is that R recognizes that for `foo` the internal variables can be discarded once the function returns but in `while` it must hang on to them (and so allocate them memory) etc

Comment: @Hugh Anyway, since there's no longer a significant difference now, and thus no point for it, I'll delete the bench! Thanks for pointing out the issue!